# Template function taking different class as parameter

Tags: c++

I keep getting that weird compile error "LNK2019 unresolved external symbol" c++.
I want to create a template function that will take different class as it's parameter. Event and Items are the classes I have created.

```
template<typename C>
void viewFunction(C customClass, char ch){
   if(ch = 'E'){
       customClass.printName();
       customClass.printPrice();
   }
   else{
       customClass.printName();
       customClass.printSize();
       customClass.printWeight();
   }
}
```

Now I called that function in main. The error happens when I try to pass in a class as my template type, I think.

```
int main{

Event myEvent1;
Event myEvent2;

Item myItem1;
Item myItem2;

viewFunction(myEvent1, 'E');

viewFunction(myItem1, 'I');

viewFunctionmyEvent2, 'E');

viewFunction(myItem2, 'I');

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please post real code which exhibits your issue. There are a bunch of typos and missing arguments here.

Comment: This code will certainly produce a bunch of errors (other than the unresolved issue)

Comment: And make sure you properly include template implementation into header.

Comment: btw.. Are you using the `char ch` parameter to indicate what type of object is the first parameter (`customclass`) ?? If yes, you misunderstood something about templates.

Comment: @tobi303 He misunderstood something about the assignment operator too 
`if(ch = 'E')`. If you want to compare for equality, use `==`

Answer (score 1):

Despite the fact that the code you have shown us is not complete nor compilable, I think I understand your error.
You seem to be checking with a **runtime** argument (your char `ch`) with a **runtime** `if` statement for which functions should be compiled in your template (at **compile time**).

Templates are not reflection or dynamic typing. The only way to have the function calls change depending on the passed-in type would be through function overload.

Function overload for template functions will eventually be done with Concepts, but is done with SFINAE in the current standard.

If only `Event` and `Item` use this function though, I'd recommend plain old function overloading with concrete types, like this.

```
void viewFunction(const Event& customClass)
{
    customClass.printName();
    customClass.printPrice();
}
void viewFunction(const Item& customClass)
{
    customClass.printName();
    customClass.printSize();
    customClass.printWeight();
}
```

Comment: "Template specialization will eventually be done with Concepts" what you're talking about isn't really template specialization, it's candidate set elimination based on type interfaces. Although  there's probably a better way of putting it than that.

Comment: Maybe I got the wrong term... I guess what you do with Concepts is actually simple function overload but with templated functions?

Comment: Concepts (in their current form) are essentially a method to enable/disable template selection based on the validity and types of expressions involving a template parameter. We do that currently using expression SFINAE.

Comment: Thanks! KABoissonneault

Comment: @ShaneJA If you copy/paste my code, make sure printName/printPrice/printSize/printWeight are const qualified so they can be called on const variables.
Or make the customClass argument not const